# Terminating app: could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm implementing a custom .xib for a UICollectionViewCell and the app is crashing with:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier DaySelectorCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

There are several answers around that suggest that the identifier has a space in it or is missing. I've triple-checked everything though, and it's still throwing.

Here's my Storyboard config for the xib:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's my DaySelectorCell.swift class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DaySelectorCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var dayOfWeekButton: UIButton!
    var dayNumber: Int = -1
}
```

And my collectionView delegate implementation:

```
extension CustomViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let days = ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"]

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let id = "DaySelectorCell"
        var cell: DaySelectorCell! = self.daySelector.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(id, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? DaySelectorCell
        if cell == nil {
            collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: id, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: id)
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(id, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? DaySelectorCell
        }

        cell.dayOfWeekButton.setTitle(days[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
        cell.dayNumber = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier` before trying to dequeue the cell

Comment: Yup, that was it. Toss it in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

If dan's answer doesn't work (and you already have registered the cell), do a clean, remove Xcode's build folder manually, quit Xcode, reboot the Mac and try again. Apple has done a very bad job with Xcode...